# How to properly display html data from an ndb.TextProperty on a webapp2 page

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

I need your help in displaying rendered html on my a webapp2 page, with data taken from an ndb TextProperty.  In my example below, I inserted

```
<b>foo</b>
```

I went to the dev server's datastore viewer and confirmed the value above is what's stored.  However, when I load the page in Chrome, it is displayed like what I inserted into the TextProperty, not a rendered version.  I did a View Source from Chrome and found that I got served this code:

```
&lt;b&gt;foo&lt;/b&gt;
```

How can I correct it?

Below are the details.

My model is as follows:

```
Models.py
=========
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
class MyPosts(ndb.Model):
slug = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
content = ndb.TextProperty(indexed=False)
```

I'm able to insert into my model a bunch of html code (only what would be in the body tag).

Here is my controller.  The query works fine as I get a record back.  Also, the paths are no problem as the page loads successfully.

```
Controller.py
=============
import os
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
import webapp2
from Models import MyPosts
class ViewMyPost(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self,title):
    ds = MyPosts.query(MyPosts.slug == title).fetch(1)
    content = str(ds[0].content)
    template_values = {
        'body': content,
    }
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'views/myview.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Here is my view.  {{ body }}'s value is provided by my controller.

```
myview.html
===========
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ body }}
</body>
</html>
```

Inserted data:
I create a short routine that inserts a record with the following value for my TextProperty

```
<b>foo</b>
```

Expected result:
I'm expecting the page to display **foo**, which is a direct substitution of {{ body }} with the TextProperty field's value.

Actual result:
The substitution sends back the entire TextProperty's value I queried.  However, somehow I get the tags converted as follows:

```
&lt;b&gt;foo&lt;/b&gt;
```

What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It was a simple fix.

On the view, I added the "|safe" filter.  Instead of {{ body }}, it now looks like this {{ body|safe }}.  

    myview.html
    ===========
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ body|safe }}
    </body>
    </html>

Here is documentation on the Safe filter
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe

Comment: Good that you found a solution. Maybe you can answer your own question and approve the answer so it does not show up in the un-answered category.

Comment: possible duplicate of [webapp2 changes html tags in pure text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374332/webapp2-changes-html-tags-in-pure-text)

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple fix.

On the view, I added the "|safe" filter.  Instead of {{ body }}, it now looks like this {{ body|safe }}.

```
myview.html
===========
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ body|safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is documentation on the Safe filter
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe